# How to hide top Navigation link My Account when signed out but still show up when signed in?

Tags: magento2, xml, magento2.4

I have been looking around on others solutions but I can't seem to find any fix with my issue.

I want to hide My Account link when your signed out. But I want to show it when your signed in. I have default.xml inside www\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Customer module that show My Account on signin and signout.

Is it possible to fix with .xml or do I have to create a header.phtml fix www\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html?

I do have a custom theme with file default.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
                   template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup" name="authentication-popup" as="authentication-popup" template="Magento_Customer::account/authentication-popup.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="authenticationPopup" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Customer/js/view/authentication-popup</item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block name="customer.section.config" class="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig"
                   template="Magento_Customer::js/section-config.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sectionNamesProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\SectionNamesProvider</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block name="customer.customer.data"  class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
                   template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
            <block name="customer.data.invalidation.rules" class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerScopeData"
                   template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data/invalidation-rules.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my-account.phtml with this code and it works fine. The My Account link flash on page reload but it's ok it a script.

```
<li data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
<!-- ko if: customer().firstname  -->
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/'); ?>" style="display:none;" data-bind="style: {display:'inline'}"><?= __("My Account"); ?></a>
<!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
"*": {
  "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
    "components": {
      "customer": {
        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
</script>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove in theme add file `Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml` or in module `Vendor/Module/view/layout/customer_account_login.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
```

Comment: I tried but it seems like it only applies to one page "Login page". When I switch to another page My Account Link returnes back.

Comment: My Account show up everywhere on the website but I want it to show when your signed inn. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create new ? Like this:

view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link-new" before='-' template="MyVender_MyModule::my-account.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

view/frontend/templates/my-account.phtml

```
<?php 
    $customerSession = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $block->getHref(); ?>"><?= __("My Account"); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

P.S. I used object manager for quick test only, its better to inject it on your construct so you need to either override Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link or create new block

Comment: Hello it's working great but there is a issue I am having. Perhaps you know a solution. When I enter category or pages the My Account Link vanish? But it returns if I go to My account page or other account related pages.

Comment: I think the php code dosn't match when your outside Magento/Customer/ location hmm...

Comment: I see2, but I'm glad you found a solution.